# Convert Data structure to Mindmap

Tags: mind-mapping

I have such a data record:

```
python_details = {
    'header': {'class', 'module', 'object'},
    'data': {'container', 'operator', 'text'},
    'statement': {'condition', 'function', 'repetition'},
    'control': {'algorithm', 'exception', 'pattern'},
    'inPut': {'database', 'file', 'user_input'},
    'output': {'console', 'desktop_GUI', 'web_application'},
}
```

Usually, I should manually write them into a mindmap such as MindNode.
Is it possible that some mind map can import such data record automatically?

Software for MacOS or Linux would be fine and I'm okay with paid solutions.

Comment: What OS should it run on, and what is your price limit if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: MacOS or Linux and okay with paid solutions. Thank you

Comment: Fine – now we ideally only need the price margin. Oh, and fine answers of course. Good luck!